# Nginx prepends response data with post request body content from its' buffer?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, graphql

For a few days i'm struggling with a strange problem in a **laravel** application that runs in a docker container on an **ubuntu** system and uses **laravel/rebing-graphql** vendor to serve **graphql** query responses.

So i'm using the **GraphiQL** interface to send graphql requests to my backend.
The result i receive for my request does not only include the valid response, but also the parameters i send along with the post request;

```
"{\"query\":\"query Users {\\n  users(pagination: {offset: 0, limit: 1}) {\\n    items {\\n      id\\n    }\\n  }\\n}\",\"variables\":null,\"operationName\":\"Users\"}{\"data\":{\"users\":{\"items\":[{\"id\":53}]}}}"
```

This response does not come with a content-type: `application/json` but as `text/html`.
It seems like the post request body is prepended to the response data of my API. This results in a JSON parse error on my client. The API data part here itself seems valid.

The most strange thing of this issue is, that it occurs on every **second**(!) request.
So about 50% of my requests are receiving a valid response which does come as json and without any prepended post request body.

I tried to analyse the root cause of this issue and i was **not** able to find a place in the code where the parameters are echoed as an additional output.

**Does an nginx configuration cause a prepending of post request body contents?**

During my further investigation, i started to replace the `index.php` file inside laravels' public directory and created a custom `index.php` which contains **nothing but an** `exit("test")`; **execution**.
The result was unexpected. I still got my post parameters prepended to the output on every second request:

```
"{\"query\":\"query Users {\\n  users(pagination: {offset: 0, limit: 1}) {\\n    items {\\n      id\\n    }\\n  }\\n}\",\"variables\":null,\"operationName\":\"Users\"}test"
```

I'm using a docker image from nginx:alpine and php:7.4-fpm-alpine.
The docker container opens a port which gets a proxy from an apache2 server which runs on my root system.

This is my nginx default config:

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name my-domain.com;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

root /var/www/html/public;

index index.php index.html;

location / {
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 1728000;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD";
        add_header Content-Length 0;
        add_header Content-Type "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,X-CSRF-Token,X-XSRF-TOKEN,Authorization";
        return 204;
    }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    if ($http_origin ~* "^(blob:)?http(s)?://www.my-domain.com(:[0-9]{2,4})?$") {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,X-CSRF-Token,X-XSRF-TOKEN,Authorization";
    }

    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass epapistagephp:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
} 
}
```

Is there anyone who already experienced this kind of behaviour or do you have a hint on where to start with a further analysation?

Thank you so much in advance!!

Greets Jules

Comment: If you've narrowed it down to either docker or nginx (or docker + nginx), then you could test a non-docker nginx server and see whether it still exhibits that behaviour.

Comment: it looks like a kind of debug mode on graphql server - laravel responsibility

Comment: @msbit I have a local docker container running with nginx and a stage server configuration.
My current fallback is to work with a pure apache setup on the remote server which does respond with a valid json. So for me it actually looks like my docker/nginx setup seems to be the problem here.

Comment: @xadm As described above - i exchanged my laravel/public/index.php with an empty file php file and it unfortunately returned the same error. Before placing my question on stackoverflow, i was talking to the maintainers of the laravel rebing graphql lib and they suggested to investigate a differente root cause - which seems to be correct

Comment: empty php still returns data? check api responses using postman - for proxied (nginx) and direct (apache) APIs/IPs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After month of struggling and using work arounds like switching to Apache2 etc...
I guess i found a solution.

As described in my original Question, the problem occured after a the nginx server was running for a while already. After a reload of the nginx server the problem disappeared temporarily. With apache2 i did not have this problem. So that way i kind of isolated the issue to nginx itself.

I now tried to disable the request caching of nginx by setting:

```
proxy_request_buffering off; <===

client_max_body_size 500M;
client_body_buffer_size 500M;
```

I also raised the buffering size for testing and it works right now.
This issue did not seem to be related to Laravel, Graphql or PHP at all.
For anyone who may stumble across this topic, i'm going to edit my original question accordingly. I hope this may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you use port 9000, you will have this problem.
Use port 8000.

Comment: Hey @Hossein Ebrahimzadeh,
thanks for you answer! Could you go more in detail and provide a bit more information why this Port 9000 may be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Would be nice to hear more details!

Comment: So far it is not possible for me to change the default port 9000 exposed by php-fpm-alpine:7.3

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most probably related to PHP's [auto_prepend_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive. Note that a specific value of "none" is required to disable auto-prepending.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was in different ports (host port is `9001` and internal port is `9000`) for `php` container in compose file:

```yaml
services:
  php:
    ports:
      - '9001:9000'
```

Change it to `9000:9000` helped, and later I just decided to leave only one port - internal, since there is no need to expose the PHP container outside:

```yaml
services:
  php:
    ports:
      - '9000'
```