# Request Data returned with JSON response

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

**Hey**

When sending a request to our Laravel API via POST method the request JSON data is sometimes returned in the JSON response, which results in an invalid response. See below for an example. The strange thing is if we restart the docker container the expected response is given for a bit, and then after a while, it goes back to adding the request data to the response.

I've spent a bit trying to find solutions but nothing I find works. So I'm hoping that someone here can help. From what I've found it seems like it's a nginx issue, and I've tried to disable cache and proxy request buffering but the issue still comes back.

**Nginx Location Config**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_no_cache 1;
        proxy_cache_bypass 1;
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
    }
```

**Our setup**

```
PHP Image: php:8.1.0-fpm-alpine3.15
Nginx Image: nginx:stable-alpine
Laravel Version: 8.78.1
```

**Request**

```
{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe"
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(SomeRequest $request)
{
    $createdModel = SomeModel::create($request->validated());

    return response()->json([
        'model' => $createdModel
    ]);
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe"
}
{
    "model" => {
        "id" : 1,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe"
    }
}
```

Comment: u have `return response()->json` so what u expect ?

Comment: Usually I'd suggest you search your code (e.g. middleware or service providers) for any sort of debug code that might be dumping variables under certain circumstances. Does it actually have `"model" => {` in the response with the `=>`? Nothing I'm aware of would produce this in that exact format.

Comment: @Wraith You have clearly not read the whole post. The issue is that NGINX adds the request data to the response given by laravel. This issue itself should be in NGINX and not in Laravel from what I've found.

Comment: @apokryfos Yes, that was my first thought too. I looked through all parts of the code and found nothing, and then I noticed it started to work as expected after a complete docker restart, and it only comes back after a while. So it can't be a code issue I caused, seems to be NGINX if anything.

Comment: switch to apache :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by disallowing external connections to PHP-FPM (Port 9000).

We tracked down the issue and found that after a while PHP changed allow_url_include from Off to On. By blocking the port, it stopped changing the value by itself.

Comment: I have the same problem, can u explain more?

Comment: I think I found the problem, the PHP parameter changes because your server is infected with kdevtmpfsi virus.

Comment: Yep, it seems I had the same situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77886417/4695280